# Getting function name and file name through another function

Tags: python

I want python to show me which function has been executed and from what file... so I have the following as `test1.py`

```
import sys,os, test2

def some_function():
    print (sys._getframe().f_code.co_name +" "+ os.path.basename(__file__) , 'executed')
    print (test2.function_details(), 'executed')
```

`test2.py` is:

```
import sys,os

def function_details():
    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name + " " +os.path.basename(__file__)
```

now when I run it

```
import test1

test1.some_function()
```

I get the following output:

```
('some_function test1.pyc', 'executed')
('function_details test2.pyc', 'executed')
```

When I try to make a function for calling the file and function of the executed, it tells me the sub function I made instead of the original.

My question is how do I modify `test2.py` so it will output

```
('some_function test1.pyc', 'executed')
('some_function test1.pyc', 'executed')
```

Comment: try this  `print (sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, os.path.basename(__file__) , 'executed') `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two issues with `function_details`:

1. The current frame is `function_details` so you need to go up one frame to get to the calling frame. To do this you pass `1` to `sys._getframe`.
2. `__file__` is the name of the current file for whatever module you happen to be in (if defined), this needs to be replaced with the `co_filename` attribute of the `f_code` object associated with the correct frame.

Correcting both of these things, we redefine function_details as:

```
def function_details():
    code_obj = sys._getframe(1).f_code
    return " ".join([code_obj.co_name, os.path.basename(code_obj.co_filename)])
```

Which produces the desired result. In my opinion, the `inspect` module accomplishes this same thing far better than using `sys._getframe` directly. Here's the new function_details written using inspect:

```
import inspect
def function_details():
    frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
    return " ".join([frame[3], os.path.basename(frame[1])])
```

Comment: I tried the `inspect` code... got this error `return " ".join([frame.function, os.path.basename(frame.filename)])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'function'`

Comment: The inspect interface changed from a tuple to a namedtuple between 2.7 and 3.5 ... I've updated the code so it works in 2.7 as well as 3.5 and 3.6 now.